# How to setup CORS setup correctly

Tags: javascript, iis, cors, sharepoint-2010

We are having an old SharePoint 2010 server, where we want to request data within the network from.

I already know that I cannot request data from other servers due to CORS, but actually as far as I understand is, that have the possibility to allow such requests. Therefore I need to modify the servers HTTP response headers, do I?

I have this setup, but it is not working actually.

Server - SharePoint 2010 - IIS:

[image]

I've set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to my notebook's name (grolne-nb090). On the JavaScript application, I have the following request defined:

```
onButtonClickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('https://my.sharepointserver.com/sites/IT/_layouts/ArchiveSearch/ajax.aspx?requestType=test', {
        method: 'GET', 
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://grolne-nb090:3000',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization,Accept',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', //'text/plain', //
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('fetch data', response);
        return response.json();
      })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('data',data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error on fetch request:', error);
    });
}
```

The current error message is this:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://my.sharepointserver.com/sites/IT/_layouts/ArchiveSearch/ajax.aspx?requestType=test'
> from origin 'http://grolne-nb090:3000' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

If I change the `mode` to `no-cors`, I get an `opaque` answer.

How can I setup the server / application correctly, that I can access this data? Which HTTP response headers I need to set on the server side and how needs the JavaScript request look like?

Just one thought, must the requester URL also use HTTPS? Can that be an issue?

### Update

I've googled a lot and it seems that a request to a SharePoint server requires authentication, which the pre-flight does not provide. So the answer from SharePoint seems to be a `401 Unauthorized` for the pre-flight and that crashes the whole request.

Now I'm searching, how I can disable authentication for a single SharePoint page... (or if it is possible)

Comment: Have you checked sharepoint logs?

Comment: Yes, but actually nothing that helps. 3 entries to the request. 2 of category "Monitoring" and 1 entry of category "Logging correlation data".

Comment: Install IIS CORS module, instead of using your custom response headers, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iis-cors-1-0 and then configure it to handle preflight requests.

Comment: IIS can set authentication for signal aspx page. However I'm not familiar with sharepoint. If sharepoint use IIS authentication, you can set anonymous authentication for signal page  by adding<location path="sitename/xxx/xxx.aspx"> to applicationhost.config.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the link to the tool. I did not know that it exists. But actually I also want to understand how the CORS works. So sometimes it's better to deep into the topic than using a tool. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. 
The problem was, that SharePoint requires authentication, which is not provided in the pre-flight. So the pre-flight gets a `401 Unauthorized` and the complete request fails.
So I read again the article of Mozilla...

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

... and saw that the pre-flight is not being done on `simple requests` (see the link above for details about `simple requests`).
So I changed the code this way:

```
fetch('https://my.sharepointserver.com/sites/IT/_layouts/ArchiveSearch/ajax.aspx?requestType=test', {
    method: 'GET', 
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
        'Accept': 'application/json'

    },
    credentials: 'include'
})
```

The "magic" is in this case is the `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'`. Then the request is handled as `simple request` and there is no pre-flight happening.

The HTTP response headers which I have set in `IIS` worked this way as you can see in the image of the opening post.